AVPlayer not using full width
On larger phones my AVPlayer, which displays a video, does not take up the entire view width as expected. It works perfectly on my iPhone 15 pro but the iPhone 16 plus in the simulator is having difficulties. I have tried a lot of things to fix it, like setting constraints on the video but nothing seems to work. I have attached a screenshot and my code below. Thanks for your help in advance!
@IBOutlet weak var cover: UIView!
private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

    private func setupVideoCover() {[
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        player?.isMuted = true
        player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
 
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        
        if let playerLayer = playerLayer {
            cover.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
            cover.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(restartVideoFromBeginning),
            name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
            object: player?.currentItem
        )
        
        player?.play()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer?.frame = cover.bounds.centered(in: cover.bounds)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupVideoCover()
    }






Did you check the cover.bounds? Is it equal to screen's size?

Can you provide screenshot of your layout structure in xib file?

Thanks for your response. I added the layout structure to my question.

As Apple's docs explains about viewDidLayoutSubviews:

This method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts
of the view's subviews have been adjusted. Each subview is responsible
for adjusting its own layout.

So when viewDidLayoutSubviews get called, your cover is not get its frame when laid out on screen yet. To set frame of playerLayer base on cover's bounds, the right way is using methods layoutSubviews of UIView:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cover: CoverView! // <- change to CoverView
    ...
}

class CoverView: UIView {
    private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        //set frame here
        playerLayer?.frame = cover.bounds.centered(in: cover.bounds)
    }
}

In your case, your code works well on iPhone 15 pro because your xib file's device might be set to iPhone 15 pro, cover's frame intially base on xib file.
